Turning SQL query result from unknown to number format
I'm running this code in Typescript, but I can't make the result from the query return into number format, only unknown :
async function withDraw(email: string, password: string, valuetowithdraw:number) {
        OracleDB.outFormat = OracleDB.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;

        let connection = await OracleDB.getConnection({
            user: process.env.ORACLE_USER,
            password: process.env.ORACLE_PASSWORD,
            connectString: process.env.ORACLE_CONN_STR

        });

        let showfunds = await connection.execute(
            `SELECT WALLET_VALUE FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE EMAIL = :email AND PASSWORD = :password`,
            [email, password]
        );

        const valueInwallet = showfunds.rows;
        
        if (valuetowithdraw <= parseFloat(valueInwallet) && valuetowithdraw > 0)
        {
            if ( valuetowithdraw <= 100){
            
            let addfunds = await connection.execute(
                `UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET WALLET_VALUE = WALLET_VALUE - (:valuetowithdraw * 0.96) WHERE EMAIL = :email AND PASSWORD = :password`,
                [valuetowithdraw, email, password]
            );
            
            return true;
        }
}

I tried to use parsefloat and number()

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now there are a lot of undeclared/unimported private/third-party things that cause my IDE to spew errors you're not asking about (e.g., "what's OracleDB? what's process? where'd the rest of the function go?"). If you make it easy for us to get started you make it more likely you'll get a useful answer.

It would also be helpful to know what the database definition is for the table & fields. And usually when a record is returned without some type of Scalar call, a whole row is returned. That means you need to access the column in the row, so it'd be something like showfunds.rows[0][0] or showfunds.rows[0]['WALLET_VALUE']
